# R dbplyr SQL Error "expecting something between Database_Name and LIMIT"

Tags: sql, r, dbplyr

Here's the connection we're working with:

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                      Driver = "[your driver's name]",
                      Host   = "[your server's path]",
                      DBCName = "[IP Address or Alias]"
                      UID    = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database user"),
                      PWD    = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database password"))
```

The command below works fine in my code, with no errors, and output that appears correct:

```
table1 <- tbl(con, "SAP_PRD_QMEL_ACQ")
```

However, when I run this line of code I get the following error:

```
table2 <- DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM SAP_PRD_QMEL_ACQ LIMIT 5")

#> Error in new_result(connection@ptr, statement) : 
#>   nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1344: 42000: [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver]
#> [Teradata Database](-3706)Syntax error: expected something between the word 
#> 'SAP_PRD_QMEL_ACQ' and the 'LIMIT' keyword.
```

When I create simple repro's to try and duplicate the error I come up empty handed. Why would I be getting this *"expecting something between Database_Name and LIMIT"* error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not going to be able to reproduce your issue, but I believe you will need to use `TOP` instead of `LIMIT`:

```
table2 <- DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT TOP 5 * FROM SAP_PRD_QMEL_ACQ")
```

Comment: and that did indeed work! Why though? What probably happened? Am decent in R but don't know much about SQL to troubleshoot this much.

Comment: There is slightly different SQL syntax depending on the type of database you're hitting, etc. Just a nuance you'll get used to checking as you keep experiencing it.

Comment: A side note -- if you're going to use `TOP N` without an `ORDER BY` you can also use the `SAMPLE` modifier - `SELECT * FROM SAP_PRD_QMEL_ACQ SAMPLE 5`